# How to parse Dictionary type with json-ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, json

I have Dictionary which will return from server, i converted it json string format as below:

```
public static class Extensions 
{ 
    public static string ToJson<T>(this T obj) 
    { 
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(); 
        try { 
            DataContractJsonSerializer jsSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T)); 
            jsSerializer.WriteObject(stream, obj); 

            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray()); 
        } 
        finally 
        { 
            stream.Close(); 
            stream.Dispose();
        } 
    } 
    public static T FromJson<T>(this string input) 
    { 
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        try {
            DataContractJsonSerializer jsSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
            stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input)); 
            T obj = (T)jsSerializer.ReadObject(stream); return obj; 
        } 
        finally 
        { 
            stream.Close(); 
            stream.Dispose();
        }
    } 
}

[WebMethod]
public string callme()
{
    Dictionary<int, string> myObjects = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    myObjects.Add(1, "This");
    myObjects.Add(2, "is");
    myObjects.Add(3, "cool");
    string json = myObjects.ToJson();
    return json;
}
```

so Result is:

```
{"d":"[{\"Key\":1,\"Value\":\"This\"},{\"Key\":2,\"Value\":\"is\"},{\"Key\":3,\"Value\":\"cool\"}]"}
```

**How I parse that in jquery? I m trying this but not help**

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "web.asmx/callme",
      data: "{}",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(msg){
          $.each(msg.d, function (i) {
          $("#data2").append(i.Key + " " + i.Value + "<br/>");
        });
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to do this things before it works:

- put a `ScriptService` attribute to your web service
- put a `ScriptMethod` attribute in your web service

If you do so, you don't even need to parse create the JSON in the server yourself. The WS infrastructure will do it for you.

Then, simply use msg.d on the client site. It will be automatically deserialized from the JSOn string.

Look here [Using jQuery to Consume ASP.NET JSON Web Services](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/) for what you need to do on client side.

[Here you have a full working sample with client and server side](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/45275/Create-a-JSON-WebService-in-ASP-NET-2-0-with-a-jQu).

Be aware that before ASP.NET 3.5 the response message brought the data directly. In 3.5 and later, the data is in the .d property of the message.

**EDIT2: Easier way to do it**
I made a mistake in the 1st edit: .asmx can't serialize a Dictionay as XML. So, when I tested the solution in the first edit via the .asmx page, I got an error. But JSON can serialize a Dictionary which has a string or an object as key.

So, you can use this class to convert your `Dictionary<int,string>` to `Dictionary<string,string>` using this generic class:

```
    public class DictionaryConverter
    {
        public static Dictionary<string,TValue> 
            ConvertDictionary<TKey,TValue>(Dictionary<TKey,TValue> dict)
        {
            Dictionary<string,TValue> newDict
                = new Dictionary<string, TValue>();
            foreach(TKey key in dict.Keys)
            {
                newDict.Add(key.ToString(), dict[key]);
            }
            return newDict;
        }
    }
```

This class can convert any Dictionary with any key type to a  `Dictionary<string,Tvalue>` dictionary, which can be serialized as JSON, but not as XML. It uses the key type `toString()` method to convert the key in string. This will work perfectly for `int` and many other types. This method could be extended to receive a delegate to convert the key to string if necessary.

On client side you get the same thing with this solution and the one in the firs edit. The advantage of the one in the first edit is that it can also support serialization to XML: you can invoke the method through the .asmx page, and use the WebMethod as a regualr XML WebMethod.

**EDIT: Serializing Dictionary<> in .asmx web service:**

The serializer used with asmx doesn't support serializing dictionaries **for XML**. You can create a custom class and convert your dictionary to a list of this custom class, which has a key and a value property (the serializer doesn't support serializing `KeyValuePair` or `Tuple`, either, so you must use your own class).

This class serves two purposes:

- It's a class that can be serialized with the serializer used by asmx for JSON
- Allows to convert a dictionary in a list of elements of the class

  ```
  public class KeyValue<TKey, TValue>
  {
      public KeyValue()
      {
      }

      public TKey Key { get; set; }
      public TValue Value { get; set; }

      public static List<KeyValue<TKey,TValue>> ConvertDictionary
          (Dictionary<TKey,TValue> dictionary)
      {
          List<KeyValue<TKey, TValue>> newList
              = new List<KeyValue<TKey, TValue>>();
          foreach (TKey key in dictionary.Keys)
          {
              newList.Add(new KeyValue<TKey, TValue> 
                { Key = key, Value = dictionary[key] });
          }
          return newList;
      }
  }
  ```

Your web method should look like this:

```
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)] // it's JSON by default
    public List<KeyValue<int,string>> GetKeyValueList()
    {
        List<KeyValue<int, string>> list
            = KeyValue<int,string>.ConvertDictionary(yourDictionary);
        return list;
    }
```

Notes:

- you can use any method name instead of `GetKeyValueList`
- the TKey, TValue must be the same types of your dictionary key and value.

On the client side you get an array of Objects with Key and Value properties, which can be accesed like this:

```
  msg.d[0].Key
  msg.d[0].Value
```

This is the jquery ajax call:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'MyService.asmx/GetKeyValueList',
        type: "POST",
        data: "{}",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (msg) {
            // use msg.d array of objects with Key and Value
        }
    });
  });
```

Comment: Then, simply use msg.d on the client site. It will be automatically deserialized from the JSOn string. so how in my json?

Comment: Look at the sample in "full working sample". Change the data returned by the web method for a dictionary and you'll see that the `.d` property of the response can be used directly on client side without deserializing it.

Comment: hmm nice thanks, infact my question was 2 parts, on of solution comes from you and the other from eli ;)

Comment: @mekici: JotaBe mentioned this, but the crux of your problem is that you're manually serializing the JSON in your service method. Since ASP.NET does that for you automatically in this case, you're ending up with doubly-serialized data. I have a post devoted to that specific problem here: http://encosia.com/asp-net-web-services-mistake-manual-json-serialization/

Comment: @DaveWard it didnt work Dictionary<int,string> error when response.. it works on Dictionary<string,string> and return type is string.(but Eli says it has to be object/array) so which one is correct? so which one is right? i dont understand

Comment: @mekici: The return type should be what you want to return, `Dictionary<int, string>` or `Dictionary<string, string>`, either one. Return a variable of that type directly and skip the manual JSON serialization.

Comment: @DaveWard but Dictionary<int,string> cant return,it gives error on console.log() but Dictionary<string,string> returns some data.

Comment: @mekici: Both definitely work. I've been returning them for years. What exactly is the error you're getting on the console when you try to use `Dictionary<int, string>`?

Comment: @DaveWard i have read your articles, and i m not doing converting to json string.. so there is error when response its {"Message":"Type \u0027System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]\u0027 is not supported for serialization/deserialization of a dictionary, keys must be strings or objects

Comment: Have a look at my edited answer. @DaveWard as of .NET 4.0, asmx service can't make JSON serialization of Dictionary, even if it's <string,string>.

Comment: @DaveWard. I can't understand it. I've keeping making tests because it was too strange... Know I've been able to serialize a <string,string> dictionary and receive it in the client without error, but I have no idea why it now works...

Comment: @DaveWard. It was a silly mistake... if you look the second edit of this answer you'll seewhat I mean.

Comment: Nice solution, I created an extension method based on your code sample to make it easier to use (see my answer below)

Answer (score 2):

```
$.each(msg.d, function() {
    $("#data2").append(this.Key + " " + this.Value + "<br/>");
});
```

Also, it appears that your serialization is not working correctly, as the response coming back isn't being entirely parsed into JSON. The contents of `d` shouldn't be a string, it should be an object/array.

Comment: Can you do `console.log(msg)` and put the response of that here?

Comment: lol. the last one: Object { d="[{"Key":1,"Value":"This...Key":3,"Value":"cool"}]"}

Comment: How about this: `console.log( typeof msg.d );`

Comment: It appears that your serialization is not working correctly, as the response coming back isn't being entirely parsed into JSON. The contents of `d` shouldn't be a string, it should be an object/array.

Comment: i used dictionary<string,string> without converting jsong string so msg.d return as object/array so your answer didnt work. what you think?

Comment: Will need you to paste the contents of `msg` again.

Answer (score 1):

Based on JotaBe answer above, I created this extension method:

```
    public class KeyValue<TKey, TValue>
    {
        public TKey Key { get; set; }
        public TValue Value { get; set; }

        public KeyValue()
        {
        }       
    }
    public static class KeyValue_extensionMethods
    {
        public static List<KeyValue<TKey, TValue>> ConvertDictionary<TKey, TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary)
        {
            var  keyValueList = new List<KeyValue<TKey, TValue>>();
            foreach (TKey key in dictionary.Keys)
                keyValueList.Add(new KeyValue<TKey, TValue> { Key = key, Value = dictionary[key] });
            return keyValueList;
        }
    }
```

Which then allows me to consume it using *{object}.ConvertDictionary()* syntax. For example:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)] [Admin(SecurityAction.Demand)]       
public List<KeyValue<Guid, string>>     Data_GuidanceItems_FileMappings()        
{
    return TM_Xml_Database.GuidanceItems_FileMappings.ConvertDictionary();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way it worked for me was

```
var $nomeP = $("#<%= tbxBuscaJornalista.ClientID %>").val();

             $.ajax({
             url: "MyPage.asmx/MyMethod",
             dataType: "json",
             type: "POST",
             data: "{ 'variableName': '"+$nomeP+"' }",
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
             success: function (msg) {
                 $.each(msg.d, function (index, value) {
                     $("#somePanel").append(index + " " + value + "<br/>");
                 });
             },
             error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                 alert("Error: " + errorThrown + " XmlRequest: " + XMLHttpRequest);
             }
         });
```

Please notice the line `data: "{ 'variableName': '"+$nomeP+"' }"` which shows I had to **enclose the variable name (same as expected in code-behind) *and the value* in single quotes**. Otherwise it would not work. Also, I tried to iterate and use `$(this).Key` and `$(this).Value` but that wouldn't work either. I was forced to use the `function (index, value)` approach.